# Evaluate $\int_0^1 {\frac{{{x^{300}}}}{{{x^3} + {x^2} + 1}}} \:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 {\frac{{{x^{300}}}}{{{x^3} + {x^2} + 1}}} \:dx$$

My try:
$$\begin{array}{l}{x^{300}} = ({x^3} + {x^2} + 1)q(x) + A{x^2} + Bx + C\\ 
\Rightarrow \frac{{{x^{300}}}}{{{x^3} + {x^2} + 1}} = q(x) + \frac{{A{x^2} + Bx + C}}{{{x^3} + {x^2} + 1}}\end{array}
$$
Now got stuck here. Also i tried to use $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$, but the denominator is more complicated than the existing one.

EDIT: As per the comments obtained that the integral is not staright forward, i would like to mention that this problem appeared in an Indian competitive exam for research admission. Here is the question asked.
[image]

Comment: This integral does not have a nice expression even if you replace the $x^{300}$ by $x^4$ or $x^5$. The result will be ugly. I'm warning you: very ugly.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+x%5E300%2F%28x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2+%2B+1%29 
Check this out, the integral doesn't look good :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: The actual question asks for only for an estimate.*

$$0< \int_0^1 \frac{x^{300}}{1+x^2+x^3}dx\leqslant \int_0^1x^{300}dx = \frac1{301} < 0.003333....$$

Comment: Minor nitpick: $1/301 \approx 0.003322\ldots$ is bigger than $0.003$. Of course, $1/301$ is still less than $0.004$, which makes $0.00$ the correct answer.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 You're right of course. Corrected.